# Will enabling application insights interrupt my azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have a Node.js functions app running in azure and it is processing thousands of requests every minute, I would like to enable Application Insights using the Azure Portal in order to diagnose an issue but I fear this may interrupt the function while it configures itself.

Is this a valid concern?

All the documentation I have found regarding Application Insights does not mention the impact on any running applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding AI integration is only a matter of adding a key to app settings, but any edits to app settings require a function app to restart, so yes it will affect your function.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests, and I made a request to it after enabling `Application Insights`. It will indeed be affected for a few seconds because it will change the `app settings` and then restart the `Azure function`.